# circledByCount returns NULL (Google+ API)

Tags: api, google-plus

I need to find out number of people who circled my Google+ account using Google API+.
Well, currently my Google+ account is circled by 84 peoples.

I tried using this people->get API to retrieve my profile.
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

All data are fine except this "circledByCount". It just returns NULL.

Does it require special permission to show up?
Btw, I'm using "login" and "email" scope to retrieve the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the circle by count for people it's only for pages

[Check here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#circledByCount)

And [here](https://developers.google.com/+/release-notes/?hl=en) for the Nov 2012 release notes on the feature:

Comment: Too bad... Any idea how to get that count?

Comment: @YansenTan yes. Check this. It's from a leaked api or somthing like this. Though it's not that accurate. http://blog.ouseful.info/2011/10/12/fragment-looking-up-whos-in-whose-google-circles/

Comment: Later in January it started working for people too.  See my answer.

Comment: @YansenTan Please also check Toms answer.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for mentioning. I think your answer should be the valid one.

Answer (score 1):

It now works for people too (as well as pages).  See this post:
https://plus.google.com/+GerwinSturm/posts/CcVdibqsqNC

But it is still limited: it only counts public followers, regardless of what permissions (scopes) you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the matter, I have found that in the call in before "circlesByCount" showed, it has changed and now this field does not appear. I think now these data are provided by the Google Domains API, but whenever I try to test the API, it returns "Error 403 forbidden" and in the documentation "You do not have permission", so I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this information via API up until 12/13/2013.  Its been MIA since then.